# I keep getting the "missing a using directive or assembly reference" in my .NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP .NET Core, however I've had coded ASP .NET before, now I am following this tutorial
"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code".

I am using Visual Studio Code.

I'm doing the "Scaffold a controller" section.

When I run the last `dotnet` statement, stated in that section, I get the error that I refer on the title (same error that shows on my problems tab inside the terminal).

Problem is, that the error can be resolved by inserting a "using" statement, as it's shown on the section "Register the database context".

I have followed thoroughly all the steps, but when it comes to `using TodoApi.Models`, I get the error

> Type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in namespace 'TodoApi' (assembly reference missing?) [TodoApi]

I have read many threads but none seem to answer the question regarding my specific case, here I'll show some of my code so you can compare mine with the Tutorial's

My `Startup.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TodoApi.Models;

namespace TodoApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do [this section?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#add-a-model-class-1)

Comment: Note that the `[asp.net]` tag refers to ASP.NET (.NET Framework) not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: There is no namespace C# can see anywhere in your project or your references, that reads `namespace TodoApi.Models`  This doesn't seem like a namespace that would be in a package, so it's (to me) something you'd write (I.e. you've forgotten to write it)

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Yes i have done the previous steps in the tutorial, as it states, i have followed every step but now im stuck with this error, here i can show you the code for the classes inside the Models folder:

**TodoItem class**

`namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
`

Comment: @CaiusJard do not know if you got the chance to review the code shown in the tutorial, but there is one of the sections, where you have to update the **Startup.cs** file, and part of the update is including 2 imports, being one of those 2, the one in line 7, inside the code i provided in the question, and that import should refere to the folder that i created previously where i have 2 classes. Thing is, i dont know why wether i use the import or not, i get the same error, and that import should be fixing it, based on the logic provided in the tutorial

Comment: @Llama Sorry for that, i thought that all related tags (similar technologies) needed to be placed used as well.

This is my first question, so from now and on i'll keep an eye on it

Comment: By the way, although the namespace will automatically be generated to match the project name and folder path, there is no actual relationship between folder and namespace, or indeed file and class. You can even have multiple namespace and class definitions within a single .cs file, etc. In short: what you're importing is not a folder, it's a namespace. If the file that declares that namespace isn't added to your project then it .NET won't be able to find it.

Comment: So @Llama, you mean that the files inside my folder aren't actually inside the project? I dont quite understand that part. Should I be including them maybe inside the `TodoApi.csproj` file? Or where should i be looking?

Comment: You should see them in Solution Explorer under your project. You should also go into the file and confirm that you can see `namespace TodoApi.Models { /* your class in TodoApi.Models here */ }`.

Comment: I hs a situation recently where I was talking with a transitioning python dev about files and namespaces and I realized that I've probably just acquired, over the time, some background understanding of files and namespaces to the extent that I don't realize it's something that people don't know/it's not really apparent. There's absolutely no relationship between the file system and namespaces, and c# is largely unconcerned with files and file systems. At the top of every file is a `namespace` declaration that represents a sort of logical version of a folder path. Every c# class exists in..

Comment: ..a namespace like files go in folders. Every clas stberefore hs a fully qualified name that is like a full path. System.Text.TegilarExpressions.Regex is a "path" to a class called "Regex" in the "System.Text.RegularExpressions" namespace. Classes can automatically "see" other classes in the same namespace, but they can't see other classes in other namespaces. There is no hierarchical visibility or importing: if you write a class and declare it to be in "System.Text" it can't automatically see "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex" because it's not the same namespace; if you write ..

Comment: "using System.Text" in a class it doesn't automatically bring in all the namespaces under it - you have to explicitly declare every namespace you want to bring in. Going back to the "no correlation between files on disk and namespaces" point, you could write all your code in a single MyStuff.cs if you wanted, and it could have multiple namespaces and classes inside, none of which are called MyStuff. We tend to organise folders and files like namespaces so there is a correlation but mainly for sanity/retrieval. If you're trying to `using ToDoApi.Models` check that you truly do have

Comment: `namespace ToDoApi.Models{ ... }` somewhere in a file somewhere in your project.